# How to avoid a mutex variable being locked twice by the same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, pthreads

`queueLIFO` is `QList`

```
//  This function is run by the thread `Producer`.
void *threadProducerFunction (void *arg)
{
    Q_UNUSED (arg);

    while (1)
    {
        if (queueLIFO.length () < 10)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexVariable);
            queueLIFO.push_back (1);
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexVariable);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexVariable);
            pthread_cond_wait (&conditionVariable, &mutexVariable);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Now, considering the following info from this link: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal

> `pthread_cond_wait()` - this routine should be called while mutex is locked, and it will automatically release the mutex while it waits.
>
> After signal is received and thread is awakened, mutex will be automatically locked for use by the thread.
>
> The programmer is then responsible for unlocking mutex when the thread is finished with it.

When the signal is received from the other thread, `pthread_cond_wait` will lock the mutex for this thread's usage, which means that in my situation the control will go in the if statement where the mutex is already locked by `pthread_cond_wait` (from else condition) and we are locking it again now.

***Have I written the code logic in a wrong way? How?***

Comment: `qt` tag is relevant here because of the use `QList` which may or may not be thread safe..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always hold the lock before you check the condition.

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexVariable);
while (queueLIFO.length() >= 10) {
    pthread_cond_wait (&conditionVariable, &mutexVariable);
}
queueLIFO.push_back (1);
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexVariable);
```